# How to use " involve in things you do not concern"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Which sentence sounds natural when you try to tell someone else who tries to intervene in a dispute you having with your friend.

> 1.It is not nice that you **are involved** in things you do not concern

> 2.It is not nice that you **are involved** in things that do not concern you

> 3.It is not nice that you **are involved** in things you are not concerned.

> 4.It is not nice that you **are involved** in things that are not concerned you.

> 5.It is not nice that you **involved** in things you do not concern

> 6.It is not nice that you  **involved** in things that do not concern you

> 7.It is not nice that you  **involved** in things you are not concerned.

> 8.It is not nice that you **involved** in things that are not concerned you.

How to say to someone "you should not intervene in situations that is not your business."

Comment: None of those is natural and some are ungrammatical. _It is not nice/right/a good idea to involve yourself in things/matters that do not concern you_.

Comment: ... or informally, "please don't stick your nose into other people's business". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick-your-nose-into-something

Answer (score 0):

Only the second is grammatical, and it is not at all idiomatic.

> It is rude to involve yourself in what does not concern you

says what you mean in a somewhat formal register. As one of the comments implied, there are plenty of informal but stereotyped ways to express the thought such as

> Mind your own business